# how to retrive substring data from column and save into different column in sql server

Tags: sql-server

```
Declare @string nvarchar(20)
set @string=(select [Bill Period] from [sqldata].[dbo].[jun1])
select substring (@string,1,3)
```

i got just single value from the entire column [Bill period],i want all the record from [Bill Period] to @string but it is not working.

how to increment table INDEX and fetch the records

```
declare @INDEX int
set @INDEX=1
while(@INDEX<3)
begin
Declare @string nvarchar(20)
set @string=(select [Bill Period] from [sqldata].[dbo].[jun1])
select substring (@string,1,3)
set @INDEX=@INDEX+1
end
```

Comment: what data [Bill Period] holds. your @string variable is nvarchar(20) make it large enough to hold data from [Bill Period].

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will do a Substring on [Bill Period] and insert the values into a column within the same table. That's what I gather you are trying to do from the subject of this question.

```
UPDATE [sqldata].[dbo].[jun1]
SET MYNEWCOLUMN = SUBSTRING([Bill Period],1,3)
```